# Android Xamarin Thread.Sleep on main thread complete blocks all threads

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin, mono, task

I am new to Xamarin and Android development, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

When I call Thread.Sleep oder Task.Wait or something similar from the main thread, it seems like the complete application instantly hangs.
Is this an expected behavior? 
e.g. I am calling Keychain.GetPrivateKey on a new created Task. This task is beeing created on the main thread. The main thread has to wait till it gets the the result of GetPrivateKey ...
But when I block the main thread by calling Task.Wait the complete Application is beeing blocked. Not even the main thread, but all threads. e.g. my fresh created task that is calling GetPrivateKey...

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Hanging the UI/Main thread on purpose is a "very bad" idea, this will result in an ANR. Do any CPU intensive work on a different thread and allow the main thread to continue to pump messages.

Comment: Stop using `Thread.Sleep` and use other approaches (a sync/await). They really should remove that method for good.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I know ..
But the problem is, that this is a very large application and I need to hang in something. Changing to a complete asynchronous model is not possible at this point...